# FFT python result

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to plot the FFT of a current waveform. I am getting as a result some that does not really make sense to me. I don't understand why I am getting 10^6 where the peak current is only 4.
Any help here? I am using numpy for FFT calculations.

I could post the plots, but I am not allowed here yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to normalise the result of a DFT/FFT (see the discussion about normalisation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition)).

[It looks like](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#implementation-details) NumPy uses the convention that the forward DFT is not divided by `N`.